# What is a Close-by Word?™

Tags: pattern, english, word-property

*This puzzle is done in honor of JLee's wonderful [Words](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22versatile%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Phrases](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) series of puzzles. JLee must be really proud of us now.*

If a word has a certain property, I call it a Close-by Word™.

In each of sentences below, one is a Close-by Word™ and one is not.  Cases and fonts have no bearing in the property of the word.  Sentences are for context only.  Only knowledge of English is required.

> 1. The (**elf / dwarf**) fights an army.
>   
> 2. The device (**slashes / reduces**) fatalities.
>   
> 3. We will (**wax / defeat**) the competition.
>   
> 4. A young man (**created / invented**) a time machine.
>   
> 5. I wish I was (**driving / flying**) across the country.
>   
> 6. People should not (**jaywalk / cross**) the street.
>   
> 7. Taxes will (**increase / decrease**) over time.
>   
> 8. The house has this (**classic / modern**) look to it.
>   
> 9. The shadow will (**loom / tower**) over us.
>   
> 10. Nothing is as (**strange / queer**) as that.

What is a Close-by Word™?

Comment: Be careful not to overuse this problem type. We've had problems with that in the past.

Comment: @JoeZ. Can't we make a tag for them? Like `phrase-tm` and `word-tm`?

Comment: @BojidarMarinov Making a tag doesn't solve the problem that *too many* problems of the tag type are being created at once.

Comment: @JoeZ. But it makes them easily searchable/filterable, and thus they are less a nuisance. (Yeah, it won't solve the problem, but the only other solution _I see_ is to close them as dupes/something)

Comment: Right, the filtering. I suppose that's at least helpful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A close-by word is

> A word whose ending letter is exactly one after its starting letter in the alphabet.

Examples given:

> **Y:** Elf (e/f) **N:** Dwarf (d/f)
>  **Y:** Reduces (r/s) **N:** Slashes (s/s)
>  **Y:** Wax (w/x) **N:** Defeat (d/t)
>  **Y:** Created (c/d) **N:** Invented (i/d)
>  **Y:** Flying (f/g) **N:** Driving (d/g)
>  **Y:** Jaywalk (j/k) **N:** Cross (c/s)
>  **Y:** Decrease (d/e) **N:** Increase (i/e)
>  **Y:** Modern (m/n) **N:** Classic (c/c)
>  **Y:** Loom (l/m) **N:** Tower (t/r)
>  **Y:** Queer (q/r) **N:** Strange (s/e)

Comment: Man, you log on to Puzzling you open up the latest tm, you finally see you can solve it, then you scroll down... Well done +1 for expedience.

Comment: @Goinghamateur the question is, how many of these do I have to slave over before I solve one? The answer is...something like 15, I guess!

Comment: Good job Bailey. i knew you'd get one eventually.

Comment: @JLee one of these days I'll get one of yours...just you wait...

Comment: oh I wouldn't be surprised at all